# Failed to import script by webworker (self.importScripts)

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

I want to use webworker to deal with the tensorflowjs model prediction tasks.But i'm failed to import the tensorflowjs script library.

```
self.importScripts("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest");
```

My project has been uploaded to Github, I hope you can download my project and help me find the problem.

Github：https://github.com/yiifanLu/webWorker

Comment: Please don't make use chase down your code or your problems. You state "_i'm failed to import the tensorflowjs script library._" but you haven't told us what the error is. Please provide the error condition that is being reported.

Comment: If i use self.importScripts("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest") in workers,it failed

Comment: _**it failed**_: Yeah. You probably won't get much help here with that level of detail. Good Luck.